# python3.5:Can't convert bytes to string implicitly

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
for url_ in url_list:
    print("Processing {}...\n".format(url_))
    r_new = rq.get(url_)
    soup = bsoup(r_new.text)
    h = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "fk-review"})
    for row in h:
        reviewfile.write(str(pe) + ') \n')
        b = row.findAll("div", {"class": "rating"})

        for a in b:
            c = a.get('style').strip()
            c = ratings_string(c)

            reviewfile.write('Ratings: ' + (c) + '\n')
            local_rating = c
        c = row.findAll("a", {"class": "load-user-widget"})

        for s in c:
            f = s.get_text().strip()

            reviewfile.write("Name: " + f + '\n')
            local_user = f

        y = row.find_all("span", {"class": "review-text"})
        for u in y:
            u = u.get_text().encode('utf-8', errors='ignore').strip()
            local_review = u

            str1 = local_review.lower()

            reviewfile.write('\n' + u + '\n  \n')

            pe += 1
```

I am trying to retrieve product reviews in text files,but its showing it can convert bytes to string implicitly,please help me out...thanks in advance

Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Mtech projects\SET 2\flip.py", line 175, in <module>
    reviewfile.write('\n' + u + '\n  \n')
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `u` object is **encoded**.
This line does it `u = u.get_text().encode('utf-8', errors='ignore').strip()`

If you add that to a `string`, python will automatically try to convert `u` to a `string`, but will raise this `TypeError` because it its encoded.

You have two options: either not to encode that text in the first place (work only with `u = u.get_text()`), or to decode it afterwards i.e. use `u.decode('utf-8')` first and then you will be able to work with strings.